# Setting up dtsearch with synonyms for acronyms

Tags: synonym, thesaurus, dtsearch

I am attempting to setup a thesaurus in dtsearch so that I can search for organisations via acronym and cant figure out how to do it properly and would appreciate any help.

[This link](http://file:///C:/Users/Christian%20Pietersen/Downloads/dtSearch%20Frequently%20Asked%20Questions%20(1).pdf) seems to hint that its possible in the FAQ but when I setup a thesaurus as shown below and search also as shown below I get the following results when the content contains "Partia e Punës e Shqipërisë"

**Thesaurus**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dtSearchUserThesaurus>
  <Item>
    <Name>P.P.S.H.</Name>
    <Synonyms>"P.P.S.H." "Party of Labour of Albania" "Partia e Punës e Shqipërisë" "PPSH" "P P S H "</Synonyms>
  </Item>
</dtSearchUserThesaurus>
```

**Searches that find matches**:

- "Partia e Punës e Shqipërisë"
- "Party of Labour of Albania"
- PPSH
- "PPSH"

**Searches that DONT find matches**:

- "P.P.S.H."
- "P P S H "
- "P P S H"
- P P S H

Answer (score 0):

ok, so this does work. It turns out that if you edit the user thesaurus in dtsearch desktop application you need to restart it in order that the edits are taken into account.